# Python error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 5 elements

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code below.

I want to open each report in my folder and copy everything I need into a new report.

But the error says:

```
PORT_result("Institution_MTD_9_28", "G:\Risk\Attribution\Fixed_Income\PORT attribution", "Daily_Performance_9_30.xlsx")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-c886cd1d12e8>", line 1, in <module>
    PORT_result("Institution_MTD_9_28", "G:\Risk\Attribution\Fixed_Income\PORT attribution", "Daily_Performance_9_30.xlsx")

  File "G:/Risk/Attribution/Fixed_Income/PORT attribution/PORT comparison.py", line 49, in PORT_result
    dt.columns = range(5)

  File "C:\Users\pjia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4385, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__

  File "C:\Users\pjia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 645, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)

  File "C:\Users\pjia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3323, in set_axis
    'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

Can someone please help?

```
def PORT_result(folder_name, location, daily_name):
   root = location + "\\" + folder_name # Set directory
   os.chdir(root) # Change current working directory to our folder directory
   report_name = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), '*.xls')  # List all the reports' name under this folder

    file_path = []
    for i in range(len(report_name)):
        path = [root + "\\" + report_name[i]]
        file_path = file_path + path    # Get the full file path of all reports

    result = []
    for m in range(len(report_name)):
        d = file_path[m]
        df = pd.read_excel(d,'Global Portfolio Summary') 
        df = list(df.index.values) 
        df = df[2] + df[7] + df[8] + df[9] + df[10] + df[11] + df[12] + df[13] + df[14] + df[15]# Slice the list and keep return info
        df = list(df) 
        df = [x for x in df if pd.isnull(x) == False] # Remove NaN 
        df = [x for x in df if x != "Global Outperformance Details"]
        idx = [j for i, j in enumerate(df) if i % 2 == 0 and i != 0]
        value = [j for i, j in enumerate(df) if i % 2 != 0 and i != 1]
        fund_name = df[0][11:]
        period = df[1][7:]
        value = [fund_name] + [period] + value
        idx = [unicode('Fund')] + [unicode('Period')] + idx
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = value)
        df2 = df2.T
        df2.columns = idx
        result = result + [df2] # Concat the result together 

    dt = pd.read_excel(daily_name)
    dt.iloc[0,0] = 'name'
    dt.index = dt.iloc[:,0]
    dt.columns = range(5)
    dt = dt.drop(0,axis = 1)
    dt.columns = ['FMTD','OMTD','FYTD','OYTD']
    dt = dt.drop('name', axis = 0)
    dt = dt.dropna(how = 'all')

    dt2 = pd.read_excel('Namelist.xlsx')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(folder_name + '.xlsx') # Write the dataframe into excel
    output = pd.concat(result, sort=False)
    output.index = range(1,len(output)+1)  

PORT_result("Institution_MTD_9_28", "G:\Risk\Attribution\Fixed_Income\PORT attribution", "Daily_Performance_9_30.xlsx")
```

Comment: You will need to add the full error stacktrace, so we can see where exactly the error ocurred.

Comment: Posted. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: The line `dt.columns = range(5)` in your code is throwing the error. It says that at that point the dataframe has only 4 columns, but you are trying to assign 5 elements as the title of the columns.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know what your code does exactly. What happens if you change `= range(5)` to `= range(4)` ? But you have to decide if that makes sense in the context of your code.